# JavaScript Arrays Counting

Tags: javascript, arrays

everyone, I  had met some problems in my codes, I want to make them count downwards.However, dunno how why it comes like below:

**My Codes:**

```js
var countx = [];

function range(start, end, step) {
  if (step === undefined) {
    step = 1;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
      countx.push(i);
    return countx;
  } else {
    for (var y = start; y >= end; y += step)
      countx.push(y);
    return countx;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(1, 10))); // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(5, 2, -1))); // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Can anyone tell me where I made it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your `countx` variable.

When you first execute `range`, `countx` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` like you expected. But when you execute it one more time, you keep pushing new values into `countx`, thus you have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2]`.

In order to fix it, put `countx` into the function so the variable is scoped to the function and will be initialized everytime when `range` is executed.

```js
function range(start, end, step) {
  let countx = [];
  if (step === undefined) {
    step = 1;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
      countx.push(i);
    return countx;
  } else {
    for (var y = start; y >= end; y += step)
      countx.push(y);
    return countx;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(1, 10))); // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(5, 2, -1))); // -> [5, 4, 3, 2]

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(1, 10).reverse()))
```

You can also use `Array.prototype.reverse` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)) to reverse the array of the array, as illustrated in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your array inside your function or it will keep its data even after calling the function.

Before 1st `range()` call : `countx = []`

After 1st `range()`call : `countx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Before 2nd `range()` call : `countx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] //Here is the problem`

```js
function range(start, end, step) {
  let countx = [];
  if (step === undefined) {
    step = 1;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
      countx.push(i);
    return countx;
  } else {
    for (var y = start; y >= end; y += step)
      countx.push(y);
    return countx;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(1, 10)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(5, 2, -1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and a check for the condition.

```js
function range(start, end, inc) {
    var i, result = [];
    inc = inc || Math.abs(end - start) / (end - start) || 1;
    for (i = start; inc > 0 ? i <= end : i >= end; i += inc) {
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(1, 10)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(5, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(7, 7)));
```

Comment: Sorry, I am now a beginner, so I haven't learned sth in your codes yet, but still great thx!!!